# An array of dictionaries into a DataFrame at ONE go in Julia

Tags: julia

I have an array of dictionaries as follows:

```
julia> data  
2-element Array{Any,1}:  
 Dict{String,Any}("ratio1"=>1.36233,"time"=>"2014-06-19T15:47:40.000000Z","ratio2"=>1.36243)
 Dict{String,Any}("ratio1"=>1.3623,"time"=>"2014-06-19T15:48:00.000000Z","ratio2"=>1.36245)
```

How can I pop this into a DataFrame at ONE go **without** looping through each dictionary and key one by one, so that I have a Dataframe like below:

```
2×3 DataFrame
│ Row │ ratio1  │ ratio2  │ time                        │
│     │ Float64 │ Float64 │ String                      │
├─────┼─────────┼─────────┼─────────────────────────────┤
│ 1   │ 1.36233 │ 1.36243 │ 2014-06-19T15:47:40.000000Z │
│ 2   │ 1.3623  │ 1.36245 │ 2014-06-19T15:48:00.000000Z │
```

Comment: May I ask why you would like to avoid a loop? Internally it is likely going to be loop anyways.

Comment: @crstnbr an elegant language as Julia should have an elegant solution ;-) I thought about looping through, but I am just so new to Julia and don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One way would be

```
julia> vcat(DataFrame.(data)...)
2×3 DataFrame
│ Row │ ratio1  │ ratio2  │ time                        │
│     │ Float64 │ Float64 │ String                      │
├─────┼─────────┼─────────┼─────────────────────────────┤
│ 1   │ 1.36233 │ 1.36243 │ 2014-06-19T15:47:40.000000Z │
│ 2   │ 1.3623  │ 1.36245 │ 2014-06-19T15:48:00.000000Z │

julia> @btime vcat(DataFrame.($data)...)
  31.146 μs (157 allocations: 12.19 KiB)
```

i.e. convert every `Dict` to a `DataFrame` and concatenate them.

More detailed explanation:

- `DataFrame(somedict)` is a constructor call which creates a `DataFrame` from a `Dict`
- `DataFrame.(arrayofdicts)`: The dot here [broadcasts](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/arrays/#Broadcasting-1) the constructor call such that all contained `Dict`s get converted to `DataFrame`s and we obtain an array of `DataFrame`s. See [Dot Syntax for Vectorizing Functions](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/functions/#man-vectorized-1) in the Julia docs for more information.
- `vcat(DataFrame.(arrayofdicts)...)`: We now [splat](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/#...) our array of `DataFrame`s into the `vcat` function, which concatenates them vertically (rows).

Comment: A nice answer. if there are many dictionaries you can write `reduce(vcat, DataFrame.(data))` to avoid splatting. As a side comment: notice that you can use `push!` a dictionary to an existing `DataFrame` which should be a bit faster than first converting it to a `DataFrame`.

Comment: Great! reduce(vcat, DataFrame.(data)) gives me "ERROR: MethodError: objects of type Dict{String,Any} are not callable Stacktrace: [1] top-level scope at none:0" Interesting to note that vcat sort columns in an alphabetical order.

Comment: Sorry, I am VERY NEW to Julia and wonder what the .(dot) and ()(bracket) in "DataFrame.(date)" mean? Could anyone please dissect and explain each to me? vcat has 27 methods and I am not sure which one we are using here:  

julia> methods(vcat)
# 27 methods for generic function "vcat":

Comment: @JuliaO I've added more detailed explanations of what is going on at each level. Let me know if this makes things clear for you.

Comment: @crstnbr You are a legend! Thank you very much.

Comment: @JuliaO if you find my answer satisfying, you may want to consider accepting it.

Comment: @crstnbr Sorry about that. I am new to Stackoverflow and just marked your answer as accepted. You are my hero!!! Have a lovely day!